# How often we're allowed to call API endpoint RabbitMQ

Tags: api, rest, rabbitmq, endpoint

I know that rabbitMQ have https://www.rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html for monitor some issue or problem with our rabbitmq, but i want that problem can send to specific email, example like this https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2021/05/alerting/.

Then i want to call this endpoint very often {rabbitmq-url}/api/health/checks/alarms (for check memory and disk space - [API endpoint](https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/v3.10.6/deps/rabbitmq_management/priv/www/api/index.html)), if got issue will send email to admin staff, but i'm not sure that is good idea or not, and what happen with RabbitMQ Service if i call that endpoint very often ?

Comment: What do you mean by "allowed"?

Comment: "allowed" i mean "can", how often we're can to call that endpoint?

Comment: What I'm asking is, who or what are you expecting to stop you? What problems are you expecting? What is stopping you trying for yourself and seeing what happens?

Comment: So i mean is, if the cron job is calling the endpoint every second, what kind of performance issue will there potentially be? That will affect process publish and consume? or maybe we cannot access RabbitMQ management UI ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] your question to clarify that, then. You could also make clear exactly what endpoint you are planning to call - [the page on Monitoring in the RabbitMQ manual](https://www.rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html) talks about several different approaches, and does talk about how often it is reasonable (and useful) to call them.

Comment: "_check memory and disk space_" - depending on what OS you are using, there must be better and more OS-specific ways (not using RabbitMQ) to check for these types of problem - alerts which will notify you of impending trouble _before_ a failure occurs.